# How to solve SBT Dependency Problem with Spark and whisklabs/docker-it-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies, sbt, dependency-management

I have written a spark structured streaming app (I'm using `Scala` with `sbt`) and now I have to create an integration test. Unfortunately I'm running into a dependency problem I can't solve. I'm using scala with sbt.

My dependency looks like the following

```scala
  val xxxxxxx            = "xx.xxxx" %% "xxxx-xxxxxxx" %"x.x.x" % "test,it" embeddedExclusions
  val sparkCore          = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0" % "provided"
  val sparkStreaming     = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0" % "provided"
  val sparkSql           = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0" % "provided"
  val sparkDse           = "com.datastax.dse" % "dse-spark-dependencies" % "6.7.2" % "provided" datastaxDseExclusions
  val sparkKafka         = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0" % "provided" sparkExclusions
  // val jacksonDatabind = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.6"
```

This `xxxxxxx` dependency in an dependency from the company which is used for integration tests (provides cassandra docker-container and so on). This dependency has the following dependencies inside:

```scala
    val dockerTestkit       = "com.whisk" %% "docker-testkit-scalatest" % "0.9.8"
    val dockerTestkitImpl   = "com.whisk" %% "docker-testkit-impl-spotify" % "0.9.8"
    val dockerTestkitConfig = "com.whisk" %% "docker-testkit-config" % "0.9.8"
```

The problem I have is the `com.fasterxml.jackson` dependency inside `org.apache.spark` and `com.whisk`

- `org.apache.spark` uses `com.fasterxml.jackson` version `2.6.7`
- `com.whisk` uses `com.fasterxml.jackson` version `2.9.5`

**First approach:**

I exclude the `com.fasterxml.jackson` dependency from `org.apache.spark`, then I get:

```scala
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.5
[info]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
[info]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
[info]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation.insert(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:131)
[info]   ...
```

**Second approach:**
I exclude the `com.fasterxml.jackson` from `xxxxxxx`, then I get:

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ReferenceTypeDeserializer
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[error]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[error]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule.setupModule(GuavaModule.java:55)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:718)
[error]     at com.spotify.docker.client.ObjectMapperProvider.<clinit>(ObjectMapperProvider.java:74)
[error]     at com.spotify.docker.client.DockerConfigReader.<clinit>(DockerConfigReader.java:58)
[error]     at com.spotify.docker.client.auth.ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier.<init>(ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier.java:47)
[error]     at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$Builder.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:3141)
```

I assume the older version of `com.fasterxml.jackson` doesn't have this class.

**Question**

- Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?
- Is there a possibility to import both `com.fasterxml.jackson` dependency versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried two approaches

**1. Approach:** Shading the dependency in the `xxxxxxx` project

I added the assembly plugin to the `plugin.sbt`

- `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.7")`

and added some shading rules to the `build.sbt`. I was creating a fat-jar for the `xxxxxxx` project

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule
    .rename("com.fasterxml.jackson.**" -> "embedded.com.fasterxml.jackson.@1")
    .inAll
)
```

That shading worked. All `com.fasterxml.jackson` dependencies were rewritten to `embedded.com.fasterxml.jackson.*` inside the `xxxxxxx` project. (I unzip the jar and decompiled the classes, to see what happended)

Unfortunately that rewriting didn't solved the problem in the `root` project (and *I didn't know why*). So I tried:

**2.Approach** Using `dependencyOverrides` in `commonSettings`

I added the following dependencies to the `root` project:

```
  val jacksonCore         = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.6"
  val jacksonDatabind     = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.6"
  val jacksonModule       = "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.6"
```

I did not exclude the `com.fasterxml.jackson` dependency from

- Apache Spark, nor
- from the `xxxxxxx`

I added the following setting to the common settings:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := library.version.scala,
    ...

  dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
    library.jacksonDatabind,
    library.jacksonCore,
    library.jacksonModule
  ),

    ...
)
```

That worked, the Exceptions are gone. Unfortunately I can't explain why this does work (and how) and why the shading didn't work. :(